# Rails 3 + Passenger + Apache: How to change the port for SSL from 443 to 8443?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, mod-ssl

My hosting service is telling me to change my SSL port from 443 to 8443 since the OpenSSL tests are failing, even though they are working in production.

I changed my apache `ports.conf` file to:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    #NameVirtualHost *:443
    NameVirtualHost *:8443
    Listen 80

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
        # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
        # to <VirtualHost *:443>
        # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
        # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
        #Listen 443
        Listen 8443
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        #Listen 443
        Listen 8443
    </IfModule>
```

I also changed my virtual hosts from `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:8443>` and restarted apache, but when I try to access the site via https, the browser says: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server`. Could it be a firewall issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first the config looks good, I assume you have ssh enabled

ssh in the machine :

- do `wget --no-check-certificate https://127.0.0.1:8443` or `curl -k https://127.0.0.1:443` (post the content)
- watch open connections and see if it's an actual apache process behind it (`sudo netstat -anp | grep 8443` or `sudo lsof | grep ":8443"`)
- is your config not overrided else where
- check your config is valid (what's the output of the `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`)
- check the apache error/request logs if you see your traces or other errors

From your laptop :

- try a nmap with this machine as target, and see if the port appear as filtered
- are you sure the dns is ok (tried with the ip address ?)

Give this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A4G7M06) a try, it's awesome to learn new troubleshooting technics.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration seams to be right, how do you try to access your site now? should be

```
https://yourdomain.com:8443/
```

Comment: it can be different reasons for example firewall, to check it you can try to use some of the console browsers (lynx for example) directly from the server